# forever.list returns null in node.js code

Tags: node.js, forever

Cannot use [forever.list](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever#foreverlist-format-callback) method in `node.js` code ...

```
var forever;

forever = require('forever');

forever.startServer();

forever.list("", function(result) {
  return console.log(result);
});
```

... prints `null` in console.

Although in terminal when run `forever list`, I see running precesses.

```
❯ forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command             script forever pid   logfile                       uptime       
data:    [0] 1QNd /usr/local/bin/node app.js 29937   29979 /Users/user/.forever/1QNd.log 0:0:26:23.55
```

And I want to get the same date inside node.js script.

Maybe I use `list` with invalid arguments. First argument `format` - I pass empty string, because don't know what to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forever.list` is a cli command, so you can not use directly in your code. If you are using forever programatically you should install [forever-monitor](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor).

So maybe you can call the cli command, e.g.:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function execute(command, callback) {
    exec(command, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    callback(stdout);
  })
};

execute('forever list', function(ret) {
  console.log(ret);
});
```

out:

```
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command       script                                            forever pid   logfile                        uptime      
data:    [0] OmsO /usr/bin/node /home/atupal/Dropbox/src/github/nodeblog/server.js 13171   13173 /home/atupal/.forever/OmsO.log 0:0:0:4.164
```

Answer (score 1):

> This answer in forever 0.15.2

Please see `forever list` command code in `cli.js`
https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/blob/master/lib/forever/cli.js#L428

```
//
// ### function list ()
// Lists all currently running forever processes.
//
app.cmd('list', cli.list = function () {
  forever.list(true, function (err, processes) {
    if (processes) {
      forever.log.info('Forever processes running');
      processes.split('\n').forEach(function (line) {
        forever.log.data(line);
      });
    }
    else {
      forever.log.info('No forever processes running');
    }
  });
});
```

Expect your code.

```
var forever = require('forever');

// If set 'true' to @format, return 'processes' is formatted strings.
forever.list(true, function (err, processes) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(processes);
});

// If set 'false' to @format, return 'processes' is object.
forever.list(false, function (err, processes) {
  console.log(err);
  console.dir(processes);
});
```